# .htaccess rewrite $_GET variables

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have the following page:

```
http://localhost/?news=19&page=2
```

I want to rewrite this so that it goes kind of as follows

```
http://localhost/news/19/page/2
```

This is my .htaccess file, but my code dont work :(

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ /?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)$ /?news=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)/page/(.*)$ /?news=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

Comment: I entered "http://localhost/news/19/page/2", but my $_GET['news'] variable echo '19/page/2', not only '19'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify more precicely what the allowed type of character is **and** you should make sure your previous rules don't cause your later rules to be ignored.

So you should put your most specific rule first and if you want digits for your news- and page ID's, you should use for example:

```
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ /?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^news/(\d*)/page/(\d*)$ /?news=$1&page=$2 [L]
                   ^^ just a digit instead of any character `.`
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)$ /?news=$1 [L]
```